# Can't access website from other networks

Tags: networking, configuration

I am trying to open a website since I was told to use and they gave me some tasks to do from there. I have always been able to use it from my work network, but not from other networks. And the guy who created and used to administer the page has gone MIA, so I can't ask him.It gives me a:
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I know some of the causes for a 403 status code, but I don't know why it would allow me to only access it from a particular network. Is there a chance that the website was configured to be used this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain websites are configured this way for security reasons. If I'm not mistaken, they use subnet filtering to make sure that the network you are trying to access the page from is on the same network as the hosting server.

Think of it like this: if you can't access the network from outside, it'd be more difficult to compromise.

Considering that the link you included was a .edu site (it also had "admin" in it, but I'm not sure if that's significant or if it's just an administration page), it would make sense for it to block incoming connections from other networks.

Comment: In some cases the client might be on the same network, but it doesn't need to be. You simply configure the server to reject requests if they don't come from certain IP ranges. (You may be thinking of routing limitations, but in that case, you would't even get a Forbidden page, the request would simply time out since it never even gets to the server.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz that was a very useful suggestion. In case I am given such competences, I might give it a try

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry I'm not allowed to vote or accept answers for now, but thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: @amygrimaldi It's okay. I'm glad I could help.